# Looking to blend two strings together for AD username

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to import around 30 users from a CSV file into Active Directory. I have the basics of how to do this and would be able to if not for our username policy. For example on my CSV I have two columns, FirstName and Surname. These are then blended together to create our usernames for example, Luke Robins would become lurobins.

So far I have:

```
Import-Csv users.csv |
  select Surname, @{n='GivenName';e={$_.'FirstName'}},
         @{n='samaccountname';e={$e = FirstName.Substring(0,2) Surname}}
```

When running this the given and surname columns come out ok, but it's the samaccountname one that's blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed two `$_` and a `+`. Also remove the assignment operation (`$e =`).

```
import-csv users.csv | select Surname,@{n='GivenName';e={$_.'FirstName'}},@{n='samaccountname';e={$_.FirstName.substring(0,2) + $_.Surname}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, so i'm getting that "$_" tells the shell to read each line in the following column. In addition however, this still has not worked, I'm still getting a blank samaccount name collum when I run it.

Comment: Ah, so I managed to get it to go by removing the "$e " before the "Firstname.substring"

Comment: @LukeRobins93 `$_` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) that contains the current object in the pipeline. Before you can access a property (like `Surname`) inside a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) you need to actually have an object first.

Comment: It is all working now, thank you restless1987 for the solution, and thank you to Ansgar Wiechers for the clarification.